# Logic in retrieving data using dates as filters using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm formulating logic now for retrieving data from database using linq but i can't really know how to do the logic.

Here is the scenario

I need to retrieve all the Events that falls in a week in the month.

(Just example)

Let us say the week starts at `1/15/2016` and ends at `1/21/2016`

Then here are the data

```
------------------------------
Starts         |  Ends
------------------------------
1/1/2016       | 1/31/2016
1/16/2016      | 1/17/2016
1/1/2016       | 1/16/2016
1/18/2016      | 1/30/2016
1/1/2016       | 1/14/2016
1/22/2016      | 1/31/2016
```

So if you based the data and the week the output should be

```
------------------------------
Starts         |  Ends
------------------------------
1/1/2016       | 1/31/2016
1/16/2016      | 1/17/2016
1/1/2016       | 1/16/2016
1/18/2016      | 1/30/2016
```

because any of the days of the data falls in the filter value which is the week

can anyone help me figuring it out. Im glad to hear any ideas from you guys. If my question is not that clear just post a comment.

Im using linq right now and i just use `>=` and `<=` but i think the situation is too unique or im not just used to it.

Comment: i try this one  `tv2Events = tv2Events.Where(h => (h.Start >= weekStart && h.End <= weekEnd) || (h.Start <= weekStart && h.End >= weekEnd)  ).ToList();`

Comment: but still not giving me the right data

Comment: Explain more detailed which events you want to collect. So, you need those which start AND end within the week or those who either start OR end in this period?

Comment: I just need those events range fall on week range.

Comment: @DatzMe Still can't understand your goal xD

Comment: Looks like OP is asking for all records which date range intersects with the specified date range.

Comment: Im sorry if im not good in explaining D. Petrov but I just want to show data that is active in a week. Im so sorry thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* you are asking for those items which are 'active' during the week, thus you are looking for:

```
query.Where(x.EndData >= weekStartDate && x.StartDate <= weekEndDate)
```

Ie something is active at some-point during the week if it hasn't already ended AND starts by the end of the week.  Depending on if you end-date is inclusive or exclusive (ie if something ends on friday does it end at the start or end of friday) you may been to change the `>=` to `>`

Comment: Thank you guys thanks for helping but this one is I think the best and easy to read answer and works for me. Thank you tolanj

Comment: Yeah this is what im looking for, active events within the week. Thanks a lot buddy

Answer (score 2):

```
 eventsCollection.Where(!(x.enddate <= startdate || x.startdate >= enddate))
```

Exclude all events where the eventenddate is less than startdate supplied or event startdate is greater than the enddate supplied.

Comment: Have upvoted as this is logically identical to mine, I find A AND B easier to 'digest' than !(!A OR !B) though (ditto !A AND !B over !(A OR B)) but that is probably personal

Comment: @tolanj I wrote this answer and then saw yours and i was like why the inverse

Answer (score 1):

```
tv2Events.Where(h => (h.Start <= weekStart && h.End >= weekEnd) || //the period include the whole week
                     (h.Start >= weekStart && h.Start <= weekEnd)  || //the period start is in the week
                     (h.End  >= weekStart && h.End <= weekEnd)) // the period end is in the week
```

Comment: yes i also tried this one and the one i message you above but it doesn't give me the right data also..

Answer (score 1):

You should combine both operators, assuming:

```
   DateTime firstDayOfTheWeek = GetMyFirstDay();
   DateTime lastDayOfTheWeek = GetMyLastDay();

   var result = eventsCollection.Where
(x => (x.endDate >= firstDayOfWeek && x.endDate <= lastDayOfTheWeek) 
|| 
(x.startDate <= lastDayOfTheWeek && x.startDate >= firstDayOfTheWeek))
```

You need to address 3 possible scenarios:

- Starts before the firstDayOfTheWeek and ends before the lastDayOfTheWeek
- Starts within the week and ends after
- Starts and ends within the week

Which you can basically reduce to either:

- The startDate has to be within the week
- The endDate has to be within the week

This of course assuming you are working with proper data (i.e. no events that start after it's supposed to end)

Answer (score 0):

Because there are some constrains `startTime < endTime` and `week.Start < week.End`, so you have to find events with condition: `(startTime <= week.Start AND endTime >= week.Start) OR (startTime >= week.Start AND startTime <= week.End)`